# how to convert char array to LPCTSTR

Tags: c++

I have function like this which takes variable number of argument and constructs
 the string and passes it to another function to print the log .

```
logverbose( const char * format, ... )
{
char buffer[1024];
va_list args;
va_start (args, format);
vsprintf (buffer,format, args);
va_end (args);    

LOGWriteEntry( "HERE I NEED TO PASS buffer AS LPCTSTR SO HOW TO CONVERT buffer to LPCTSTR??");

}
```

Instead of using buffer[1024] is there any other way? since log can be bigger or very smaller . All this am writing in C++ code please let me know if there is better way to do this .....

Comment: The `T` in `LPCTSTR` means the type changes depending on if you have a Unicode build or not.  Are you using a "Unicode character set", or an "Multi Byte Character Set" in your project settings?

Comment: Investigate where LOGWriteEntry is a macro for LOGWriteEntryA or LOGWriteEntryW depending on the setting of TCHAR.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You can probably just pass it:</s>

```
LOGWriteEntry (buffer);
```

If you are using ancient memory models with windows, you might have to explicitly cast it:

```
LOGWriteEntry ((LPCTSTR) buffer);
```

correction:

LPCTSTr is Long Pointer to a Const TCHAR STRing.  (I overlooked the TCHAR) with the first answer.

You'll have to use the [MultiByteToWideChar function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to copy `buffer` to another buffer and pass that to the function:

```
w_char buf2 [1024];
MultiByteToWideChar (CP_ACP, 0, buffer, -1, buf2, sizeof buf2);
LOGWriteEntry (buf2);
```

Comment: The only reason you would need to cast it is if you're using a Unicode build, in which case a simple cast isn't nearly enough.

Comment: @wallyk: Well, now the answer is wrong in multibyte character builds, in which case a simple cast is the answer.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  Windows is so wonderful!  Which is more likely?  `char` is always 8 bit, but TCHAR could be UTF-16 or UTF-8 depending on the build.  In my experience (pre-2005), it was always 16.

Comment: @wallyk: It ought to be "UTF16" nowadays, and I'd assume most large projects are, but I think a default-created project is still "multibyte character", so it could be either way.  (Windows never uses UTF-8 for anything, you have to convert it yourself.  Multibyte = code pages)

Comment: It's supposed to be a build time setting based on values of macros `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE`.  IMO the most sane thing to do is always define these and treat everything as `WCHAR`.  Otherwise you use the misnamed and poorly supported "ANSI" functions which is a bad idea.  Get used to it: 16-bit characters is the way to go on Windows, pay no attention to other platforms with their "utf8-everywhere" utopia.  :P

Comment: I use macros like this, which aren't super performant, but they're easy: http://ideone.com/okuKEz

Answer (score 1):

A good way to proceed might be from among these alternatives:

- Design the `logverbose` function to use `TCHAR` rather than `char`; or
- Find out if the logging API provides a `char` version of `LOGWriteEntry`, and use that alternative.
- If no `char` version of `LOGWriteEntry` exists, extend that API by writing one. Perhaps it can be written as a cut-and-paste clone of `LOGWriteEntry`, with all `TCHAR` use replaced by `char`, and lower-level functions replaced by their ASCII equivalents. For example, if `LOGWriteEntry` happens to call the Windows API function `ReportEvent`, your `LOGWriteEntryA` version could call `ReportEventA`.
- Really, in modern applications, you should just forget about `char` and just use `wchar_t` everywhere (compatible with Microsoft's `WCHAR`). Under Unicode builds, `TCHAR` becomes `WCHAR`. Even if you don't provide a translated version of your program (all UI elements and help text is English), a program which uses wide characters can at least input, process and output international text, so it is "halfway there".

Comment: I'm fascinated that you recommend making `char` versions of everything, and then explicitly say "forget about `char` and use `wchar_t` everywhere"

Comment: @MooingDuck "char happens" in otherwise wide-char programs. Maybe there is some legacy code that outputs chars and needs to log or whatever. "Convert everything to wide chars" might not be the right solution for that program.  And I didn't say to make char versions of *everything*; just that function and the API that it needs!

Comment: @MooingDuck: Or you might be dealing with Internet protocols. Would it really make sense to do SMTP and convert the protocol conversation from 7-bit ASCII to UTF-16?